# Having trouble creating a data model design in Parse

Tags: parse-platform, database-design

I'm having trouble figuring out a data model for my project. I'm using Parse as the backend.

I intend to have users who are in groups, and the groups have text posts. What should be classes, and what should be rows in those classes.

I'm guessing a good way to do this would be, have a **group**, **user**, and **post** **class**.

The columns for the **group class** would be: **GroupID**, **GroupName**, **postID**, **UserID**

The columns for the **user class** would be: **UserID**, **GroupsUserBelongsTo**, **user name**, **password**, **email**

The columns for the **post class** would be: **UserIDPostBelongsTo**, **GroupID**, **TextFile**, **TimeCreated**

Is there anything I'm missing, or I should change.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking is a very SQL / rows based way and you shouldn't, this isn't SQL, it's objects and relationships.

So, your classes are fine, and the actual data is fine, but where you're using ids you should be using relationships. Post should just have a pointer to user. Perhaps, don't bother with a relationship from user to groups (you can query that using the other relationship), though you can, particularly if you will have lots of users / groups.

You may also want to consider roles to provide security for the groups.